# View loads offline, but NOT in the live site

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, templates, codeigniter-hooks

Well, that's pretty weird...

I uploaded my 100% working website to my server and it suddenly seems to have stopped working.

**To be specific :**

- At the Home controller, everything goes smoothly but the `$this->load->view(` part seems to be ignored
- I've turned `error_reporting` on, and set `ENVIRONMENT` to `development`, but it's still not showing *any* errors at all

**My `Home/Index` controller :**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('theme');
        $themes = $this->theme->getLatestThemes(100);

        $this->load->model('post');
        $posts = $this->post->getLatestPosts(3);

        echo "ENVIRONMENT : ".ENVIRONMENT; // Shows up fine

        $this->load->view('home',array("themes"=>$themes, "posts"=>$posts));

        echo "AFTER"; // Shows up fine
    }
}

?>
```

Any ideas? What could be going wrong?

---

***P.S.** Please, note that all db settings have been updated accordingly, as well as the `.htaccess` file (even when I erased everything in there though, in case there was some mistake, it still made zero difference)*

---

#### UPDATE :

I seem to have narrowed down the cause of this weird issue...

When I disable a hook, the view loads fine. However, I still do not know why it's working locally and not online?

**in hooks.php**

```
$hook['display_override'] = array(
'class' => 'Minifyhtml',
'function' => 'output',
'filename' => 'Minifyhtml.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks',
'params' => array()
);
```

**hooks/MinifyHtml.php**

```
<?
    function getAd($matches)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        return $CI->load->view("template/adsense",array("ad"=>$matches[1]),true);
    }

    class Minifyhtml {

        function output()
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $buffer = $CI->output->get_output();

            $search = array(
                '/97ed7d147627494968723a2bc9f346c699e2a004gt;[^\S ]+/s',    //strip whitespaces after tags, except space
                '/[^\S ]+97ed7d147627494968723a2bc9f346c699e2a004lt;/s',    //strip whitespaces before tags, except space
                '/(\s)+/s',    // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
                '/<!--(.*)-->/Uis'
                );
            $replace = array(
                '>',
                '<',
                '\1',
                ''
                );

            $ad_regex = "/%%([A-Za-z0-9:\-]+)%%/i";

            $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
            $buffer = preg_replace_callback($ad_regex, "getAd", $buffer);

            $CI->output->set_output($buffer);
            $CI->output->_display();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: How does `BASEPATH` get defined?

Comment: @jcsanyi It's one of those globals defined by CodeIgniter, at start-up.

Answer (score 0):

OMG... so stupid.

`'filename' => 'Minifyhtml.php'`, in hooks.php

had to be changed to `'filename' => 'MinifyHtml.php'` (capital `H`) - not sure why this worked locally, though... :-S

Comment: LOL, no worries, that gonna happen for each of us ;)

Comment: @HashemQolami Indeed... :)

Comment: That is why CI suggests using underscore than camelCase.